# share variable between components angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to share variable between two independent components.

It works fine until I refresh the page, the logout button disappear.
I'm sharing the variable for the purpose of showing or hiding this button(show it when user is connected)

When I use ngAfterViewChecked it works but I found that it's not a good practice.

login.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  private isLoggedIn = new Subject<boolean>();

  getIsLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
      this.updateIsLoggedIn(true);
      return this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
    }else{

      return this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
    }
 }

  updateIsLoggedIn(state: boolean) {
   this.isLoggedIn.next(state);
 }
```

The following method is executed when I click the login button

login.component.ts

```
login(AuthenticationRequest){
    this.loginService.login(AuthenticationRequest).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem('token',res.jwt);
        this.router.navigate(['patient/calendrier']);
        this.incorrect = false;
        this.loginService.updateIsLoggedIn(true);

      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.incorrect = true;
      }
    )
  }
```

header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription;
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.today = new Date();
    this.subscription = this.loginService.getIsLoggedIn().subscribe(
      state => { this.isLoggedIn = state;
      }
    )
  }


  logout() {
    console.log();
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    this.loginService.updateIsLoggedIn(false);
    location.reload();

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

header.component.html

```
...
<button *ngIf="isLoggedIn"  nz-button (click)="logout()">Se déconnecter</button>
...
```

Comment: If you refresh page you lose the data from your service, it's not a db to keep data!

Comment: Solution1 cookies -- solution 2 `window.localStorage`

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX I'm already using localStorage but the problem is that I should detect changes in the other component when logging out or in

Answer (score 1):

I'd say [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is more suitable for handling user sessions. Incase of verifying tokens, it might also serve you well to test it's validity. Try the following:

login.service.ts

```js
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  private isLoggedInSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedInSource.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

  public getIsLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (tokenValid()) {
      this.updateIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
    return this.isLoggedIn$;
  }

  public updateIsLoggedIn(state: boolean) {
   this.isLoggedInSource.next(state);
  }

  private tokenValid(): boolean {
    let result = false;
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token !== null) {
      const exp = (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp;
      if ((Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000)) < exp) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) operator avoids pushing redundant values.

login.component.ts

```js
login(AuthenticationRequest) {
  this.loginService.login(AuthenticationRequest).subscribe(
    res => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', res.jwt);
      this.router.navigate(['patient/calendrier']);
      this.incorrect = false;
      this.loginService.updateIsLoggedIn(true);
    }, 
    error => {
      this.incorrect = true;
    }
  );
}
```

header.component.ts

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private subscription;
  private isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.today = new Date();
    this.subscription = this.loginService.getIsLoggedIn().subscribe(
      state => { this.isLoggedIn = state; }
    );
  }

  private logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
    this.loginService.updateIsLoggedIn(false);
    location.reload();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

header.component.html

```
<button *ngIf="isLoggedIn"  nz-button (click)="logout()">Se déconnecter</button>
```

Comment: I got an error in this line ```private isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedInSource.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();``` the property ```distinctUntilChanged ``` does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>

Comment: Make sure you import it explicitly: `import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';`. I've updated the code.